# How to clear constraints for all objects?

Tags: constraints

Is there any way to remove, apply or clear all the constraints for all the objects (or selected) in scene?

Comment: Object>>Constraints>>Clear Object Constraints (Ctrl+Alt+C)

Comment: @FFeller The shortcut Ctrl+Alt+C is _Clear Pose Constraints_, not _Clear Object Constraints_... at least not in my Blender version.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Context sensitive, depending on current mode.

Comment: @Nathan Well sure, I thought to clear constraints from objects you should be in _Object Mode_ but when I'm trying it, Ctrl+Alt+C does absolutely nothing and when I'm looking in the keymap, I have no shortcut there for clearing object constraints. And I didn't change my keymap from the default settings...

Comment: @GordonBrikmann Good to know, just adding because in my version (basically default keymap, pre2.8 interface on initial startup) it works for object mode, but in pose mode, it will clear pose constraints.  Which makes sense-- a lot of pre 2.8 keymapping makes more sense than post, but I do miss F2 renaming, which for some reason can't be keymapped....

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann
 In different modes (Object mode and Pose mode) you can assign the same shortcut for different things. ctrl+alt+c is both for me by default.

Comment: @FFeller "you can assign", yeah but is it assigned to Object Mode in Blender's default settings? Not in mine... ‍♂️

Comment: @GordonBrikmann I'm still use the 2.79 settings (this option is on the splash screen at the first start).

Comment: @FFeller Okay, but I wouldn't presume everyone's doing that and for beginners it might be unclear why the shortcut doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a bit unspecific on what you want to achieve. Just removing/clearing the constraints would also remove the effect they had on the objects, while applying usually means you want to preserve the effect/transformation created by the constraints. If you want to apply and remove the constraints, do the following (skip 2. if you don't want to apply the transforms):

1. Select the objects on which you want to apply and remove the constraints.
2. Go to menu *Object* > *Apply* > *Visual Transform*, shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Now choose *Object* > *Constraints* > *Clear Object Constraints*.

[image: apply transforms]

[image: clear constraints]

Comment: Beautiful! It works great